# Can't use HSQL sequences in JUnit

Tags: spring, junit, hsqldb, spring-batch

I'm trying to run a JUnit test class for my  Spring-Batch application. I had to create the following tables: http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html. I create them in my initialization database script, including the following:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ;
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION;
CREATE SEQUENCE BATCH_JOB_SEQ;
```

The creation of all sequences and tables didn't generate any errors. But while executing my JUnit test, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain identity(); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_SEQ
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.HsqlMaxValueIncrementer.getNextKey(HsqlMaxValueIncrementer.java:119)
```

That is caused when the class HsqlMaxValueIncrementer runs:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into " + getIncrementerName() + " values(null)");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Which version of HSQL are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HSQLDB the 3 tables need the ID field.

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (
           ID BIGINT IDENTITY
);
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ (
           ID BIGINT IDENTITY
);
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_SEQ (
           ID BIGINT IDENTITY
);
```

Reference: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql